# how do I concatenate a single column numpy array with a four column numpy array?

Tags: arrays, numpy, concatenation

I have a numpy array which is a column vector. I have another numpy array which is 4 column vectors of the same length as the single column vector. How do I make an combined array that is [x,5]?

Comment: 'column vector'?  what's the shape?  (x,) or (x,1)?

Comment: (x,) is the shape. The comments below by@MarkDickinson though answers my question. I wish I had the reputation to vote up the answer.

Comment: Then technically it isn't a 'column vector'.  It's just a vector, or 1d array.  When concatenating arrays, the distinction matters.

Comment: @hpaulj ok so in matlab the distinction matters because matlab stores and operates on data in columns not rows. The distinction matters in numpy because ?

Comment: In MATLAB, `1:5` is a row vector `(1,5)`, and its transpose `(1:5).'` a column.  `[y, x.']` would do your concatenation if `y` is `(5,4)`.  `numpy` provides a third possibility, `(5,)`.  `np.array(range(1,6),ndmin=2).T` generates the equivalent column vector.

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, please accept it like [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251399/4367286)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `numpy.hstack` you can stack vectors horizontally (when the vectors are already given in column shape for some reasons)

```
import numpy

a = numpy.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
#[[ 0  1  2  3]
# [ 4  5  6  7]
# [ 8  9 10 11]]

b = numpy.arange(3).reshape(3,1)
#[[0]
# [1]
# [2]]

numpy.hstack((a,b))
#[[ 0  1  2  3  0]
# [ 4  5  6  7  1]
# [ 8  9 10 11  2]]
```

Edit:
Otherwise `numpy.stack_column` is more appropriate to add a 1d-array to a 2d-array as no reshape is required as pointed out by Mark, thanks!

Comment: `numpy.column_stack` also works, and saves the need to reshape the column vector.

Comment: Awesome thank you both for your answers. I found that hstack worked but I come from a matlab background and figured their had too be a way to do this in one simply.

Comment: @Mark: Indeed a very useful command ... didn't know about that :)

Comment: Functions like `hstack`, `vstack`, and `column_stack` use some sort of reshaping before concatenating.  `column_stack` uses `np.array(..., ndmin=2).T`.

Comment: A key difference from MATLAB - a matrix is 2d (or more).  A numpy array may be 1d or even 0d.

Comment: `dstack` is also worth mentioning (that would be "depth" stack, or along third axis)